# Parsing a complex xml using SAXParser in java

Tags: java, xml, sax

How to use SAXParser for parsing a XML in which major things are in attributes and xml in format of :

```
<code code="SPECIALNOTE"></code>
<text><![CDATA[<strong>** New York State approval pending. This test is not available for New York State patient testing **</br> ]]></text>
```

I need to access the hierarchy level till  tag and then use the  tag to get the value of it to show it to the screen.Java is the PL i am using and XML in which i want to use a SAXParser technique..i am a newbie, please help me out...

Thanks in advance,
El Nino

Comment: How to proceed in SAX Parser, as in DOM parser we can access it by looping through and get by tag name.. but in SAX how to get the hierarchy value and condition that if the tag contains a check value and take a inner tag value in correspondence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`startElement()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html#startElement%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.Attributes%29) has a argument called `attributes`. This will hold the attribute information for the element the parser has arrived at. You can then use that information how you need to continue farther with parsing.

If you need a more general guide to how to write your handler, [here is a tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/).

Comment: How to proceed in SAX Parser, as in DOM parser we can access it by looping through and get by tag name.. but in SAX how to get the hierarchy value and condition that if the tag contains a check value and take a inner tag value in correspondence...